conjunction: being that; being as; being as how
I saw two sentences below in a dictionary.
https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/23a4002703f34cb9b4de3025eed0b7ac

ex1) Being that/as it was too late to go home, we stayed the night at a hotel.


ex2) It should be her decision, being as how she's the one who's paying for it.

Could I change the "being as how" in ex2) to "being that" or "being as" as ex3) or ex4)?
ex3) It should be her decision, being that she's the one who's paying for it.
ex4) It should be her decision, being as she's the one who's paying for it.
The question is whether 'being that, being as, being as how' are interchangeable for each other. My dictionary says these conjunctions are informal, colloquial, dialectal, archaic.

Yes, they are, especially being as how.  Standard English would use Since or simply as in ex.1, and probably seeing as/that or considering that in ex.2.

In all your examples "being …" can be replaced with "because". As your dictionary implies this is no longer common usage in any of the main countries where English is spoken.

I have downvoted being as how you failed to cite the dictionary so we could examine the context in which those sentences are supplied as examples.  being as how is the sort of "conversational clumsiness" that usage manuals try to eliminate from prose.  In American English, it would mark the speaker as a "hick".

https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/23a4002703f34cb9b4de3025eed0b7ac don't downvote please.
